# Tensorflow Keras poor accuracy on image classification with more than 30 classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification

I have problem with image classification using Keras. I always got poor accuracy with only 0.02. I tried to follow [cat and dog classification](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/master/ml/pc/exercises/image_classification_part1.ipynb) which has 0.8 in accuracy but it could not work in my case with 30 classes.

Let say I have datasets with around 100K of images and categorized within 30 classes. I split it with 80% for training and 20% validation.

The structure folder is look like this.

```
|-train
|---category1
|---category2
|---category3
|---category4
|---.....
|---category30
|
|-validation
|---category1
|---category2
|---category3
|---category4
|---.....
|---category30
```

Each category in train folder contains around 2000 to 4000 images.

**my model**

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([    
    Conv2D(kernel_size=3, filters=16, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=[150,150, 3]),
    Conv2D(kernel_size=3, filters=30, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    Conv2D(kernel_size=3, filters=60, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    Conv2D(kernel_size=3, filters=90, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    Conv2D(kernel_size=3, filters=110, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    Conv2D(kernel_size=3, filters=130, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(kernel_size=1, filters=40, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    Dense(1,'sigmoid'),
    Activation('softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=.00001),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Train the datasets**

```py
history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=100,  
      epochs=10,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=50, 
      verbose=2)
```

And I always got low accuracy like 0.02 or 0.03

```
Epoch 6/10
100/100 - 172s - loss: -1.8906e+01 - accuracy: 0.0265 - val_loss: -1.8923e+01 - val_accuracy: 0.0270
Epoch 7/10
100/100 - 171s - loss: -1.8773e+01 - accuracy: 0.0230 - val_loss: -1.8396e+01 - val_accuracy: 0.0330
Epoch 8/10
100/100 - 170s - loss: -1.8780e+01 - accuracy: 0.0295 - val_loss: -1.9882e+01 - val_accuracy: 0.0180
Epoch 9/10
100/100 - 170s - loss: -1.8895e+01 - accuracy: 0.0240 - val_loss: -1.8572e+01 - val_accuracy: 0.0210
Epoch 10/10
100/100 - 170s - loss: -1.9091e+01 - accuracy: 0.0265 - val_loss: -1.8685e+01 - val_accuracy: 0.0300
```

So how can I improve my model? is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should have as many neurons in your final layer as you have classes. So your final dense layer should be:

```
Dense(n_classes),
Activation('softmax')
```

Also, since your task is not binary classification, your loss function should be:

```
loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
```

`from_logits=True` should only be set to true if you don't have an activation function on your final dense layer (which you have). If you want to keep `from_logits=True`, remove the `softmax` activation.

For this loss function, make sure that in your `flow_from _directory` call, that `class_mode='categorical'`.

One more thing, your learning rate seems very small. The default learning rate of 0.001 should be fine.

Comment: If I keep `from_logits=True` and the `softmax` layer, what happens to my model? I think it's like double softmax layer, apart from "it's unnecessary", what is the real harm?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should change the following lines:

```
  Dense(1,'sigmoid'),
  Activation('softmax')
```

into:

```
Dense(number_of_classes,'softmax'),
```

and down in the model.fit()

```
loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
```

where number_of_classes is the number of categories in your case (30).

Second of all, since you have a very small number for each of your classes, you should use  a pretrained network. A good starting point would be a ResNet50.